# How to Scroll into selected item in listbox in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want  to scroll into selected item in a list box .for that now I am using  one line of code in `Listbox1_SelectionChanged` event, but scroll is not working. I tried the same in a button click that is working fine .

```
Listbox1.ScrollIntoView(Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.SelectedIndex]);
```

Comment: Try to UpdateLayout() before Scrolling in to the view..

Comment: @bit - is there any method to update the ui

Comment: Listbox1.UpdateLayout()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used in my solution first updated UI and the called ScrollIntoView it works fine:

[follow this link for more info](http://wp7appdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/scrolling-to-the-selected-item-listbox/)

```
Listbox1.UpdateLayout();
Listbox1.ScrollIntoView(Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.SelectedIndex]);
```